# How to capture table row on button click to add css class knockout js

Tags: css, json, knockout.js

i have table with data and data populated by knockout js foreach bind.
i would like to know how to access specific table row's data when it gets updated.

if i could access table row then could add css class to that tr. my objective is to do bit color animation for a row which will be updated just clicking on button. when any data will be push to table row clicking on "Update Data" button then i want to add a class to that table row and after few minute remove that class too. hence i am new so no logic is coming to my mind to achieve this....any help would be appreciated. thanks

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/62Ls6x9n/157/

### full code

```
<button data-bind="click: AddNewData">Add New Data</button>
<button data-bind="click: UpdateDataByIds">Update Data</button>
<br><br>
      <table class="imagetable">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th> 
        <th>Status</th> 
        <th>Edit</th> 
        <th>Delete</th> 
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: Stocks">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td> 
            <td data-bind="text: price"></td> 
            <td data-bind="text: status"></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.UpdateData">edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.DeleteItem">delete</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

table.imagetable {
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #999999;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.imagetable th {
    background:#b5cfd2 url('cell-blue.jpg');
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #999999;
}
table.imagetable td {
    background:#dcddc0 url('cell-grey.jpg');
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #999999;
}

var StockItem = function(_id, _name, _price, _status){
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(_id);
    self.name = ko.observable(_name);
    self.price = ko.observable(_price);
    self.status = ko.observable(_status);
};

var data= [ 
new StockItem("12345", "Acme Widget 1", "£25.99", "In Stock"), 
new StockItem("67890", "Acme Widget 2", "£28.99", "In Stock"),                                                               new StockItem("11123","Acme Widget 3","£15.99", "In Stock"), 
 new StockItem("14156", "Acme Widget 4", "£33.99", "In Stock")
];

var NewData = [new StockItem("99999", "HSL Limited", "£78.99", "In Stock")];

var appViewModel = function() 
{
    var self = this;
    self.Stocks = ko.observableArray(data);

    self.AddNewData = function(){
        self.Stocks.push.apply(self.Stocks,NewData);
    };

    self.DeleteItem = function(dataContext){
        var itemToDelete = dataContext;
        self.Stocks.remove(itemToDelete);
    }

    self.UpdateDataByIds = function(){
        var id1 = '11123';
        var id2 = '12345';
        self.UpdateById(id1,null,null,"Out of Stock");
        self.UpdateById(id2,null,"31.45",null);
    };

    self.UpdateById = function(_id, _name, _price, _status){
        var matchedItem = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.Stocks(),          function(item) {
            return item.id() === _id;
        });

        if (matchedItem != null){
            if (_name != null) matchedItem.name(_name);
            if (_price != null) matchedItem.price(_price);
            if (_status != null) matchedItem.status(_status);
        }
    };

    self.UpdateData = function(dataContext){
        var itemToEdit = dataContext;
        itemToEdit.status("Out of Stock");
    };
};

var vm = new appViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `Mutated` array to your view-model:

```
self.Mutated = ko.observableArray();
```

And upon updating / adding, add the item id to the array:

```
self.Mutated.push(_id);
```

Then in your HTML, have a `mutated` class on each `<TR>` that is indeed mutated:

```
<tr data-bind="css: { mutated: $root.Mutated.indexOf(id()) > -1 }">
```

And the CSS:

```
table.imagetable tr.mutated td { background-color: red; }
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62Ls6x9n/162/)

Comment: do not understand this `$root.Mutated.indexOf(id()) > -1` ? can we add. i also like to remove mutated class after few sec? how to have this feature.

Comment: This line simply checks if the row id exists in the `Mutated` array. See http://jsfiddle.net/62Ls6x9n/163/ for removal after few seconds.

Comment: can we do the same with different approach? can we access dom element from this view model function `self.AddNewData = function()` ? guide me if it is possible. thanks

Comment: You can also add a `mutated` flag to the item itself. Your view-model cannot access the DOM elements being affected because it will defeat the whole purpose of MVVM and in Knockout, that's the role of the binding-handlers (There are exceptions though, like the `click` handler that *is* passing the element being clicked to the model).

Comment: @haim770 Here's a fiddle that uses the mutated flag and a mutated CSS class. http://jsfiddle.net/62Ls6x9n/173/

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692884/how-to-capture-table-row-on-button-click-to-add-css-class-knockout-js/30693113#30693113   i want a color animation like stackoverflow. initially add red color and after 500ms that red color fade to default one....i guess this can not be done by mutating....what is your suggestion. thanks

Comment: @haim770 u gave two jsfiddle link. what is the difference between Mutated array and mutated flag ? would u mind to explain. thanks

Comment: @Thomas, Whether to store ids of mutated objects in array or mark each item with `mutated` flag is a matter of personal preference in this case. As for the 2 Fiddles: In the second Fiddle I added the code to remove the item id from the `Mutated` array after 1 second (using a timeout registered on `subscribe`).

Comment: @haim770 one request. i post a thread whose url is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697599/knockoutjs-trying-to-do-color-animation-for-tr-by-custom-binding   can u please see this post and answer...........i stuck to do the color animation by custom binding.

Comment: i update the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/o47suzqo/12/ still fade in effect is not very smooth. so looking for suggestion to have smooth fade in effect. thanks