# How to do the color animation like stackoverflow

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Here is one link which play the color animation

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697599/trying-to-do-color-animation-for-tr-by-custom-binding?noredirect=1#comment49464218_30697599)

Even i need some kind of fade-in and fade-out color animation with jQuery. I want when user click a button then my div will fade similar like stackoverflow.

I tried this way but i guess my effect is close to stackoverflow but not same.
here is my code which i tried with CSS

```
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function( event ){
        var hash = '#'+event.fragment;
        var originalcolor = $(hash).css('background-color');
        $(hash).css('background-color', 'yellow');
        setTimeout(function () {
          $(hash).css('background-color', originalcolor);
        }, 1500);

  });
```

Comment: you can use it with css3 and `.addClass()/removeClass()`.

Comment: All you need is `transition: background-color 500ms;` on whatever your `hash` element  is, and this should work.

Comment: transition does work for old browser ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "old browsers". Here's the table of compatibility http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jquery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
var $myElement = $('#myElement');
$myElement.animate({'background-color': '#F4AC01'}, 1000, function () {
    $myElement.animate({'background-color': '#fff'}, 1000, function () {
        console.log('Animation finish!')
    })
});
```

Comment: `jQuery.animate()` is not able to animate background color (without additional plugins at least).

Comment: here is my jsfiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/6k3rnaa1/ which i create with ur code. plzz have a look and tell me is it similar like stackoverflow. change if anything need to modify.

Comment: I never seen the code of stackoverflow, but it works as it is in stackoverflow.

Comment: It works because OP included jQuery UI, vanilla jQuery does not offer color animation: *For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used* - right from the jQuery docs you linked to.